# Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Line 1 Error converting data type nvarchar to real

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Presently, I am executing the following query and receiving the above error message:

```
SELECT dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.ItemID,
       dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.EDGRDataID,
       dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.LineItemID,
       dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.ZEGCodeID,
       dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.DataValue,
       dbo.tblBC.AcceptableValues,
       dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.DataUnitID,
       dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.DataDate,
       dbo.tblBC.DataTypeID,
       CASE
         WHEN DataTypeID = '{5951994B-BF47-4117-805D-B8F85FAB76A8}'
              AND ISNUMERIC(DataValue) = 1 THEN ( CASE
                                                    WHEN CAST(DataValue AS FLOAT(8)) >= 0 THEN 1
                                                    ELSE 0
                                                  END )
         ELSE 0
       END AS ValidPositiveNumericValue,
       CASE DataTypeID
        WHEN '{A6317BA5-F8FB-4866-A26B-24594650C2DC}'THEN ( CASE UPPER(DataValue)
        WHEN 'TRUE' THEN 1
        WHEN 'FALSE' THEN 1
        WHEN 'YES' THEN 1
        WHEN 'NO' THEN 1
        WHEN 'Y' THEN 1
        WHEN 'N' THEN 1
        WHEN '0' THEN 1
        WHEN '1' THEN 1
        ELSE 0
      END )
         WHEN '{5951994B-BF47-4117-805D-B8F85FAB76A8}' THEN ISNUMERIC(DataValue)
         ELSE 1
       END AS ValidDataType,
       dbo.tblZEGCode.ZEGCode,
       dbo.qryOtherFieldDataFieldName.FieldName
FROM   dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.qryOtherFieldDataFieldName
         ON dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.ItemID = dbo.qryOtherFieldDataFieldName.ItemID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblBC
                       RIGHT OUTER JOIN dbo.tblZEGCode
                         ON dbo.tblBC.BCID = dbo.tblZEGCode.BCID
         ON dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.ZEGCodeID = dbo.tblZEGCode.ZEGCodeID
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: What version of SQL Server are you on?

Comment: Ah no [`TRY_CONVERT`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh230993.aspx) available then.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest looking for the bad value that is preventing you from converting to type float (aka real) with the trick of concatenating `e0` to the value before testing it:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE
   DataTypeID = '{5951994B-BF47-4117-805D-B8F85FAB76A8}' -- the type for float
   AND IsNumeric(
      DataValue + CASE WHEN DataValue NOT LIKE '%[ed]%' THEN 'e0' ELSE '' END
   ) = 0
   AND IsNumeric(DataValue) = 1
;
```

This works in SQL Server 2000 and up.

**UPDATE 1**: Since you shared that you want to find only those that can't be detected easily, not all those that aren't truly numeric, I added the second `IsNumeric`.

**UPDATE 2**: You finally told me that some of your values already have scientific notation in them. This is *quite easily* handled. I have updated the query above. Please try it on for size.

To anyone using SQL Server 2012 or higher, this problem is probably best solved with [TRY_PARSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213126.aspx):

```
SELECT TRY_PARSE(Value AS float)
```

This will convert any values to float that can be, but will return NULL for any others. Thus, you can use this to check if conversion to float will fail by checking to see if this expression `IS NULL`.

Comment: Thanks @MartinSmith, I have updated my answer. The SQL code was just a tad impenetrable before you did your public service formatting job, so I missed that part. `IsNumeric('$e1') = 0`, at least.

Answer (score 0):

Created the following cursor to cause the query to execute one row at a time, which allowed me to identify the problem data row:

```
SET ARITHABORT OFF
SET ARITHIGNORE ON
SET ANSI_WARNINGS OFF

DECLARE @msg VARCHAR(4096)

BEGIN TRY

    DECLARE @itemid AS NVARCHAR(255);

DECLARE C CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR
    SELECT ItemID AS itemid
    FROM dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource;

OPEN C;

FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @itemid;

WHILE @@fetch_status = 0
BEGIN

    SELECT  dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.ItemID, dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.EDGRDataID, dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.LineItemID, 
            dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.ZEGCodeID, dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.DataValue, dbo.tblBC.AcceptableValues, 
            dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.DataUnitID, dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.DataDate, dbo.tblBC.DataTypeID, 
            CASE WHEN DataTypeID = '{5951994B-BF47-4117-805D-B8F85FAB76A8}' AND ISNUMERIC(DataValue) = 1 THEN (CASE WHEN CAST(DataValue AS Float(8)) 
            >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) ELSE 0 END AS ValidPositiveNumericValue, 
            CASE DataTypeID WHEN '{A6317BA5-F8FB-4866-A26B-24594650C2DC}' THEN (CASE UPPER(DataValue) 
            WHEN 'TRUE' THEN 1 WHEN 'FALSE' THEN 1 WHEN 'YES' THEN 1 WHEN 'NO' THEN 1 WHEN 'Y' THEN 1 WHEN 'N' THEN 1 WHEN '0' THEN 1 WHEN '1' THEN 1 ELSE
            0 END) WHEN '{5951994B-BF47-4117-805D-B8F85FAB76A8}' THEN ISNUMERIC(DataValue) ELSE 1 END AS ValidDataType, dbo.tblZEGCode.ZEGCode, 
            dbo.qryOtherFieldDataFieldName.FieldName
     FROM   dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.qryOtherFieldDataFieldName ON dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.ItemID = dbo.qryOtherFieldDataFieldName.ItemID LEFT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.tblBC RIGHT OUTER JOIN
            dbo.tblZEGCode ON dbo.tblBC.BCID = dbo.tblZEGCode.BCID ON dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.ZEGCodeID = dbo.tblZEGCode.ZEGCodeID
     WHERE dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource.ItemID = '' + @itemid + ''

    FETCH NEXT FROM C INTO @itemid;
END

CLOSE C;

DEALLOCATE C;

END TRY 
BEGIN CATCH
SET @msg = 'Failure occurred attempting to execute qryOtherFieldDataVerify.';
EXEC ApplicationManagement.dbo.spLogProcedureCall 
    @ObjectID       = @@PROCID,
    @AdditionalInfo = @msg;
RAISERROR(@msg, 0, 1);
END CATCH   

DECLARE @returnCode int
SET @returnCode = CASE WHEN @msg IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
SELECT @returnCode AS ErrCode;
```

Comment: Using a cursor is an awful way to deal with the problem. Instead of try-until-you-fail, how about just querying for the problem data?

Comment: Could you please tell me, how do you query for the problem data?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion.  Unfortunately, I'm running 2008.

Comment: The first part of my answer has a solution that works in SQL Server 2000 and up.

Comment: The first part part returns many rows, which is helpful; however, I still need to examine every row to find the one particular problem row that is causing the error.

Comment: Then add `AND IsNumeric(DataValue) = 1`! You can modify your original query to correctly detect non-numeric values safely using my technique. There is no need to do it row by row.

Comment: Thank you, that returned fewer rows to analyze.  Ultimately, however, your suggestion still returns several rows versus finding the exact problem row using cursors.

Comment: Isn't that better? Mine returns ALL the problem rows, but yours stops on the first one there is. Don't you want to fix/examine them all at once, instead of waiting to see the next problem until after you fix the first one?

Comment: Yours returns all the scientific notation values which don't cause a problem plus the one row causing an error.  Mine only returns the error-causing rows.

Comment: **FINALLY** you actually give me a hint to what your data consists of. That was like pulling teeth! If you would only have given me more details sooner, I could have helped you. This is very frustrating. I have updated my answer to show you how to deal with values that already have scientific notation in them.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one -

```
SELECT
      s.ItemID
    , s.EDGRDataID
    , s.LineItemID
    , s.ZEGCodeID
    , s.DataValue
    , t.AcceptableValues
    , s.DataUnitID
    , s.DataDate
    , t.DataTypeID
    , ValidPositiveNumericValue =
        CASE WHEN DataTypeID = '{5951994B-BF47-4117-805D-B8F85FAB76A8}' AND ISNUMERIC(DataValue) = 1 
            THEN CASE WHEN CAST(DataValue AS FLOAT(8)) >= 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
            ELSE 0
        END
    , ValidDataType =
       CASE 
        WHEN DataTypeID = '{A6317BA5-F8FB-4866-A26B-24594650C2DC}'
            THEN CASE WHEN UPPER(DataValue) IN ('TRUE', 'FALSE', 'YES', 'NO', 'Y', 'N', '0', '1') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END 
        WHEN DataTypeID = '{5951994B-BF47-4117-805D-B8F85FAB76A8}' 
            THEN ISNUMERIC(DataValue)
         ELSE 1
       END
    , c.ZEGCode
    , f.FieldName
FROM dbo.qryOtherFieldDataVerifySource s
LEFT JOIN dbo.qryOtherFieldDataFieldName f ON s.ItemID = f.ItemID
RIGHT JOIN dbo.tblZEGCode c ON s.ZEGCodeID = c.ZEGCodeID
LEFT JOIN dbo.tblBC t ON t.BCID = c.BCID
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion; however, I'm still receiving the same error.